# Series which are not Fourier Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

How to show that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin{(nx)}}{\log n}
$$
not the Fourier series of any function?

I have shown that the series is convergent by Dirichlet test.

Let $a(n)=\frac{1}{\log n}$.
What is $\sum (a(n))^2$, to apply Parseval's theorem?

Comment: See [Katznelson](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Harmonic-Analysis-Yitzhak-Katznelson/dp/0486633314) chapter I, 4.2. Briefly, a sine series $\sum a_n \sin{(nx)}$ is *not* a Fourier series of an integrable function if $a_n \gt 0$ and $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{n} = \infty$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sin \frac{nx}{ \log n}$ or $\frac{\sin nx}{\log n}$?

Comment: @MattN: the former has no chance of being a Fourier series...

Comment: @t.b.: google link to [An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis 4.2](http://books.google.com/books?id=gkpUE_m5vvsC&pg=PA24) (perhaps... :-))

Answer (score 4):

Since $\Bigl\lvert\sum\sin(n x)\Bigr\rvert\leq M$ for $M<\infty$ and $\Bigl\{\frac{1}{\log(n)}\Bigr\}\to 0$ monotonically, by Dirichlet's test, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)}$ converges.

---

If $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)}$ is a Fourier series, by Parseval's theorem, there exist a Riemann integrable function $f$ such that 
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\lvert f(x)\rvert^2dx=2\pi\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log^2\lvert n\rvert}
$$

### Theorem:

Suppose $a_1\geq a_2\geq\cdots\geq 0$. Then the series $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum 2^ka_{2^k}$ converges.
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{k^2\log^2(2)}\geq\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}=\infty
$$

---

Therefore, by Cauchy's condensation test, the $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log^2\lvert n\rvert}$ does not converge which contradicts Parseval's theorem. Thus, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\log(n)}$ is not a Fourier series.

Answer (score -3):

Suppose that it is the Fourier series of $f(x)$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$, namely,
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{\log n},\quad x\in(-\pi,\pi).$$
Then by Pareraval's Identity,
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \, dx=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\log^2n}=\infty.$$

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  Parseval's identity applies when $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2\,dx<\infty$.  What about the case when that integral is infinite but $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)| \, dx<\infty$?  Those functions also have Fourier series.

Comment: . . . also, did  you intend $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2\,dx$ where you wrote $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: The proof is correct if we assume f is Riemann integrable though...